# Custom UITableViewCell no member named error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subclassing

When Subclassing a `UITabelViewCell` in swift im getting a error that the member named does not exist

Custom Cell

```
import UIKit


class CustomRow: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var namelabel: UILabel!

}
```

Accessing it in tableview class

```
// --- Table view ---

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return data.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomRow") as! CustomRow


            cell.namelabel.text = person.valueForKey("engineerName") as? String <-----cant access nameLabel


            return cell
    }
```

Error: `does not have a member named 'name label'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot one thing

```
var cell:CustomRow = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomRow") as! CustomRow
```

because `CustomRow` should have `nameLabel`

or use it directly

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomRow") as! CustomRow
```

Both will work.

Comment: Will do, i've upvoted, have to wait 12mins to accept - your answer was that quick